# Fetching data using api with react typescript and spring boot

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spring-boot

I have a simple tsx file below.
I already have springboot set up and I were able to access the data through localhost on chrome.
My question is how can I connect to spring boot with react using the api and get access to those data?

```
function getdata(props) {
   return ( 
      <div>
        //data
     </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could connect with apis by using the simple ajax calls.
For this you could use axios if you're not using redux.
If you are using redux, you could use any middleware for the same such as saga or epics.
I am currently using epics with react in my project. You could use epic if you have good understanding of observables